# Join selected anonymous object with another table

Tags: c#, linq

I have a join

```cs
var result = 
    from a in dbContext.As
    join b in dbContext.Bs on a.Id equals b.A.Id
    select new { A = a, Ds = b.AList.Select(listItem => listItem.ObjectOfTypeD) }
    join c in dbContext.Cs on ANONYMOUS_OBJECT.Ds.Id equals c.ObjectOfTypeD.Id
```

how can I join the contents of my select clause with `dbContext.Cs`?

Comment: If there is a property `b.A` then you don't need the first join. You probably don't need the second join either. This question can only be answered when the class model and the relationships are visible. It's usually not a good idea to ask questions based on pseudocode.

Answer (score 0):

You can continue Query Syntax LINQ expression by `into` operator after `select`:

```cs
var result = 
    from a in dbContext.As
    join b in dbContext.Bs on a.Id equals b.A.Id
    select new { A = a, Ds = b.AList.Select(listItem => listItem.ObjectOfTypeD) }
    into s
    join c in dbContext.Cs on s.Ds.Id equals c.ObjectOfTypeD.Id
    select new { s, c };
```